# Shouldn't agua be profundo instead of profunda?

Tags: traducción, género

According to Duolingo, the phrase "The water is not deep" should be translated "El agua no es profunda." instead of what I guessed, "El agua no es profundo."

Since "agua" is masculine (el), shouldn't the adjective indicate that by having an "o" ending (rather than the feminine "a" ending?

If Duolingo is correct (they probably are), why this seeming anomaly?

Comment: Agree, check the link. Agua is feminine, but just because it starts with an "a"  and we want to avid the awful "la aXXX" sound, we use a different article. That doesn't change the gender of the word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agua is feminine: *Agu**a***. But we use *El* in singular words that start with *A* and have the strong syllable first. Plural would be *Las aguas*. This is done because *La agua* is hard to pronounce.

Comment: Exceptions: "La Haya", "La hache", and I don't know if any other.

Comment: @rodrigo También la a y la alfa (letras), la Ámsterdam y otras ciudades y países como la Austria, sustantivos sexuados invariables como la árabe (cuando se refiere a una mujer árabe), y nombres femeninos con artículo como la Ana.

Comment: Y muy al azar, la árbitra.