# El agua, La Argentina, why?

Tags: género

I saw this [Why is "agua" masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? "El agua" / "Las aguas"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la)

but no one told the reason why Argentina is not El Argentina as agua in el agua

Comment: As the best answer on the post you linked to said, we only use "el" when the feminine word begins with a stressed "a". In "Argentina", it is the "i" which is stressed.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate. This can be answered with other existing questions. The problem is that there is not a single answer that answers this. Check [why some country names have articles in front of the name](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/672/5481) as well as [why we use the masculine article for "agua" or "aguila"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/44/5481). [This question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8786/5481) can help too too.

Comment: Also, note that we say "el agua" and "el águila" (note the accent in the `a`, it can be seen well in this word, unlike `agua`) but "la araña". As tree house said, it depends on if the first `a` is stressed or not.